# e.getSource Buttons in a Checkers game are not working. GUI

Tags: java, drjava

I am programming using DrJava. All of this code fall under the action performed section in a GUI.

Everything in here is working properly except for those 2 e.getSource buttons.

The 2 statements are the if (`e.getSource()== b[a-9]`) and if (`e.getSource()== b[a-7]`).

I added action listeners to every button.

When I click on the button, no actions are being performed.

I put a System.out.println to see if they work, but once clicked on, it is also not printing it onto the screen.

This obviously means they're not working, but why? If you want the whole code to try, just ask and I'll give it to you. This is my CPT for grade 11.

```
if(player==1) 
{
    for(int a=41; a<64; a++) 
    {
        if (e.getSource()==b[a]) 
        {
            board();
            b[a].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
            if(!b[a].getText().equals(b[a-9].getText())&&!b[a].getText().equals(b[a-7].getText())) 
            {
                b[a-9].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
                b[a-7].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));

                //THIS IS NOT WORKING____________________________________
                if (e.getSource()== b[a-9])
                {
                    System.out.println("NOT WORKING");
                    b[a-9].setText(piece1);
                    b[a].setText("");
                    board();
                    player2();
                    player=2;
                }

                if (e.getSource()== b[a-7])
                {
                    System.out.println("NOT WORKING");
                    b[a-7].setText(piece1);
                    b[a].setText("");
                    board();
                    player2();
                    player=2;
                }
                //___________________________________________________________      
                if(e.getSource()==b[47])
                {
                    board();
                    b[47].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
                    if(!b[47].getText().equals(b[47-9].getText()))
                    {
                        b[47-9].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
                    }
                }
                if(e.getSource()==b[48])
                {
                    board();
                    b[48].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
                    if(!b[48].getText().equals(b[48-7].getText()))
                    {
                        b[48-9].setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }      
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you should provide minimal, runnable examples. What your print proves is that the source of the event is not the same referenced by your various b[] elements, but without the code that sets up the listener and initializes b[] it's not possible to help

Comment: I can send the whole code if that would help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have this check:

```
if (e.getSource()==b[a])
```

Then if that condition is true you have this check:

```
if (e.getSource()== b[a-9])
```

Well that can never be true because the same button can't equal button (a) and (a-9) at the same time.

Same with the (a-7) condition. It can never be equal to (a) and (a-7) at the same time.

Comment: ohhhh ok that makes sense. So I took it out of the (e.getSource()==b[a]) and placed it in the (int a=41; a<64; a++) loop. This makes the button work but not in the way I want I to. Is there a way in which i can keep it inside the (e.getSource()==b[a]) and still make it work?